# Javascript getting a single element on Firefox, and an array on other browsers

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, browser

So i have a form in html, with each of the options being like this: (A plethora of full pages like this can be found [here](http://mmoviles.webs.upv.es/test_fundamentos/))

```
<input id="Q1opc1" name="Q1" type="radio" value="Q1opc1" /> 
    <label for="Q1opc1 ">Froyo </label> 

    <label id="Q1extr" style="display: none">&nbsp&nbsp Recuerda que los nombres se asignan en orden alfabético.
</label>  </br>
```

The submit button:

```
    <input
        onclick="comprobarRespuesta(Q1opc2,Q1,Q1extr,Q1FraseCorrecto,Q1FraseIncorrecto,Q1GrCorrecto,Q1GrIncorrecto);"
        type="button" value="Comprobar" />
```

First i pass the right answer, then the name of the radio buttons, then the id of the hints, then the id of the right and wrong phrases and images to be shown/hidden as apropiate.

The JavaScript function looks like this:

```
function comprobarRespuesta(correcta, radio, extra, sicorrecto, sinocorrecto,
            iconoTick, iconoWrong) {
        var tmpChoice = radio;
        var c = radio.length;
        var correct = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < c; i++) {
            if (tmpChoice[i].checked == true) {
                extra[i].style.display = "inline";
                if (tmpChoice[i].value == correcta.value) {
                    sicorrecto.style.display = "inline";
                    sinocorrecto.style.display = "none";
                    iconoWrong.style.visibility = "hidden";
                    iconoTick.style.visibility = "visible";
                } else {
                    sinocorrecto.style.display = "inline";
                    sicorrecto.style.display = "none";
                    iconoWrong.style.visibility = "visible";
                    iconoTick.style.visibility = "hidden";  
                }
            } else {
                extra[i].style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    };
```

The problem i have is that in most browsers i have been able to test, the variable called "extra" in my function is an array of elements, so accesing extra[i] has no problems, but in firefox, extra is only the first label with that id, and not all of them, so JavaScript outputs "TypeError: extra[i] is undefined" to the console, exits, and my form behaves as it was not working at all

Comment: Those variables you are passing to the function in the onclick, where are those coming from? Looks like you are relying on elements with an id or name automatically creating JS objects of the same name in the global scope? That is something you shouldn’t be doing, it’s just wrong. If you want to access HTML elements on the page via JS, then you have to select them first, f.e. via `document.getElementById`, `getElementsByName` etc.

Comment: So i have to pass the name or id as a string, then in javascript call document.getElementById()? Does that allow me to access to multiple elements with the same id? So far it seems like only the first element is retrieved, no matter what browser.

Comment: You can not have multiple elements with the same ID within an HTML document, IDs must be unique.

Comment: I fixed my code by actually using `document.getElementById, getElementsByName` and giving the "extr" labels unique Ids with the same name, so they can all be retrieved at once. The answer is below.

Answer (score 0):

So with the pointers from CBroe, I rewrote part of the code so that it uses the proper document.getElementById()/document.getElementsByName(), and doesent repeat ids. Now it needs much fewer paramenters to be passed, and works fine on all browsers i have tried and should work properly on all others as I am using the proper functions. Here is my working code, now in less pieces (HTML):

```
<form  name="Q4Form">
    <h5>
Cada ítem de menú tiene una serie de atributos. ¿Cuál de los siguientes NO es un atributo de menú?


        <img id="Q4GrCorrecto"  height="16" alt="Correcto"  style="visibility: hidden" width="16"
            src="http://www.dcomg.upv.es/~jtomas/bien.jpg" /> 
        <img id="Q4GrIncorrecto" height="16" alt="Incorrecto" style="visibility: hidden" width="16" 
            src="http://www.dcomg.upv.es/~jtomas/mal.png"/>
    </h5><h6>
    <input id="Q4opc1" name="Q4" type="radio" value="Q4opc1" /> 
    <label for="Q4opc1 ">icono
</label> 

    <label id="Q4extr1" name="Q4extr" style="display: none">&nbsp&nbsp</label>  </br> 
    <input id="Q4opc2" name="Q4" type="radio" value="Q4opc2" /> 
    <label for="Q4opc2 ">método que se ejecutará al seleccionar una opción
</label> 

    <label id="Q4extr2" name="Q4extr" style="display: none">&nbsp&nbsp</label>  </br> 
    <input id="Q4opc3" name="Q4" type="radio" value="Q4opc3" /> 
    <label for="Q4opc3 ">título que se mostrará
</label> 

    <label id="Q4extr3" name="Q4extr" style="display: none">&nbsp&nbsp</label>  </br> 
    <input id="Q4opc4" name="Q4" type="radio" value="Q4opc4" /> 
    <label for="Q4opc4 ">identificador (id)</label> 

    <label id="Q4extr4" name="Q4extr" style="display: none">&nbsp&nbsp</label>  </br> 

            </h6>   
    <label id="Q4FraseCorrecto" style="display: none">
        Respuesta correcta
    </label>
    <label id="Q4FraseIncorrecto" style="display: none">
        Respuesta incorrecta
    </label> </br> 

    <input
        onclick="comprobarRespuesta(2,4);"
        type="button" value="Comprobar" />
</form>
```

onClick variables are the correct answer and the number of the question

JavaScript:

```
function comprobarRespuesta(numCorrecta, numPregunta) {
        var radio = document.getElementsByName("Q"+numPregunta);
        var sicorrecto = document.getElementById("Q"+numPregunta+"FraseCorrecto");
        var sinocorrecto = document.getElementById("Q"+numPregunta+"FraseIncorrecto");
        var iconoTick = document.getElementById("Q"+numPregunta+"GrCorrecto");
        var iconoWrong = document.getElementById("Q"+numPregunta+"GrIncorrecto");
        var extra = document.getElementsByName("Q"+numPregunta+"extr");
        var c = radio.length;
        for (i = 0; i < c; i++) {
            if (radio[i].checked == true) {
                extra[i].style.display = "inline";
                if (i == numCorrecta-1) {
                    sicorrecto.style.display = "inline";
                    sinocorrecto.style.display = "none";
                    iconoWrong.style.visibility = "hidden";
                    iconoTick.style.visibility = "visible";
                } else {
                    sinocorrecto.style.display = "inline";
                    sicorrecto.style.display = "none";
                    iconoWrong.style.visibility = "visible";
                    iconoTick.style.visibility = "hidden";  
                }
            } else {
                extra[i].style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    };
```

Now I am geting the variables inside the function, and i ned so much fewer inputs because the names or ids of the elements are hightly predictable.